# Yii 2 - How to redirect to certain frontend page in root if logged and redirect to frontend login page if is guest in root?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, yii2

I have a problem. I tried to use an .htaccess in the root folder to redirect like this:

- **localhost/planificacion_talleres/** redirect to **localhost/planificacion_talleres/frontend/web/index.php?r=planificacion** if User is logged
- **localhost/planificacion_talleres/** redirect to **localhost/planificacion_talleres/frontend/web/index.php?r=site** If User is guest.

But I don't know how to redirect using the same .htaccess to other pages using a condition. I need help, please

Comment: are you need to redirect using .htaccess?

Comment: I think this is the only way to redirect from the root to a page

Answer (score 0):

I think it is bad idea to redirect using `.htaccess`, because in this case you can't manage these redirects depending on other conditions.

I recommend to use application redirects, for instance:

```
class DefaultController extends \yii\web\Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $targetRoute = \Yii::$app->user->isGuest
            ? ['site']
            : ['planificacion'];

        return $this->redirect($targetRoute);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I need to create this controller in the root folder of the project?

Comment: No. Please see here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html#getting-started